# awk : if >=4 lines in a row begin with + or - don't print record

Tags: bash, shell, awk, gawk

I'm trying to use awk to read a file and only display lines that do no begin with a + or - 4 or more times in a row. gawk would be fine too. Each grouping is separated by a blank line.

Here's a sample from the file, these are the lines I **do not** want printed:

```
+Host is up.
+Not shown: 95 closed ports, 3 filtered ports
+PORT     STATE SERVICE   VERSION
+23/tcp   open  telnet
+9100/tcp open  jetdirect

-Host is up.
-Not shown: 99 closed ports
-PORT     STATE SERVICE VERSION
-5900/tcp open  vnc
```

A sample from the file which I **do** want printed ( not 4 or more in a row ):

```
-Not shown: 76 closed ports, 18 filtered ports
+Not shown: 93 closed ports
PORT    STATE SERVICE VERSION
+514/tcp open  shell
```

I'm learning how to use awk at the moment as I've been reading O'Reilly's awk & sed but I'm a little stumped on this problem. Also, if anyone cares to, I wouldn't mind seeing non-awk ways of solving this problem with a shell script.

Thanks!

Comment: It's unclear what exactly you're looking for here. Can you give a more complete example, such as a full (if short) input file and the expected output from same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understood your question, the input file have records as paragraphs, so you will need to separate them with blank lines. I assumed it for next script:

Content of `script.awk`:

```
BEGIN {
        ## Separate records by one or more blank lines.
        RS = ""

        ## Each line will be one field. Both for input and output.
        FS = OFS = "\n"
}

## For every paragraph...
{
        ## Flag to check if I will print the paragraph to output.
        ## If 1, print.
        ## If 0, don't print.
        output = 1

        ## Count how many consecutive rows have '+' or '-' as first
        ## character.
        j = 0

        ## Traverse all rows.
        for ( i = 1; i <= NF; i++ ) {
                if ( substr( $i, 1, 1 ) ~ /+|-/ ) {
                        ++j;
                }
                else {
                        j = 0
                }

                if ( j >= 4 ) {
                        output = 0
                        break
                }
        }

        if ( output == 1 ) {
                print $0 "\n"
        }
}
```

Assuming following test input file as `infile`:

```
+Host is up. 
+Not shown: 95 closed ports, 3 filtered ports
+PORT     STATE SERVICE   VERSION

+Host is up. 
+Not shown: 95 closed ports, 3 filtered ports
+PORT     STATE SERVICE   VERSION
+23/tcp   open  telnet
+9100/tcp open  jetdirect

-Host is up. 
-Not shown: 99 closed ports
-PORT     STATE SERVICE VERSION
-5900/tcp open  vnc 

-Not shown: 76 closed ports, 18 filtered ports
+Not shown: 93 closed ports
PORT    STATE SERVICE VERSION
+514/tcp open  shell
```

Run the script like:

```
awk -f script.awk infile
```

With following output (first record because it doesn't reach to four consecutive rows, and second record because it has a different line between them):

```
+Host is up.
+Not shown: 95 closed ports, 3 filtered ports
+PORT     STATE SERVICE   VERSION

-Not shown: 76 closed ports, 18 filtered ports
+Not shown: 93 closed ports
PORT    STATE SERVICE VERSION
+514/tcp open  shell
```

Comment: This works nicely. Thank You! Originally, I was trying to do something like /^[+-]/ ~ $1 with the default FS because I was unaware of another way to match pattern. Setting RS to a blank line was something I thought would work but I didn't know how to match the [+-] since I've only done field matching so far. 
Thanks again.

Comment: Since you don't provide the print(f) actions how does your script know when to print the record? output is just a normal variable right? I'm confused as to what provides the actual output action.

Comment: @jonschipp: The instruction `print $0 "\n"` inside the last condition `if ( output == 1 )`. The `output` flag is reset when found a paragraph with at least 4 consecutive lines with your condition. By default is set. `$0` has the whole paragraph and an extra `\n` is to separate pragraphs in output too. Is this what you are asking or did I misunderstood you?

Comment: Yes, that's it. I just didn't notice the print $0 in the code section of your post ( I didn't scroll down to see it ) . I switched to a Mac and the scroll bar doesn't show up unless hovered upon in Chrome. My mistake.

Answer (score -1):

```
awk '{if(NF>3 &&( $0 ~ /\+/ || $0 ~ /-/) ) print $0}' test.txt
```

Comment: Useless use of `cat`. Also, it doesn't answer the question, which has to do with the number of lines in a block, not the number of fields in a line.

Comment: In awk, you should never write `{ if( expr ) print $0}` in an action statement.  Instead, just write `expr` as the pattern statement.